# Remove highlight of a submenu when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a submenu that expands on clicking on a toggle text using HTML CSS and JavaScript. The problem is that, after every third consecutive click, the toggle text is highlighted. How do I prevent this from happening?
I'm asking this because all the toggle submenus I've seen on professional websites don't get highlighted. I am attaching part of the code for reference.

```js
const toggleElements = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle');

toggleElements.forEach((toggle) => {
  const content = toggle.nextElementSibling;

  // Add a click event listener to toggle the content visibility
  toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (content.style.display === 'block') {
      content.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      content.style.display = 'block';
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="toggle">
    <a>Fit</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="wrapper-content">
      <p> test1</p>
      <p>test2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to set the css `user-select:none;` on your element to prevent the text selection.

Comment: hey, Im still facing it.

Comment: `user-select: none` should do the trick for you. which browser you're using? Try adding a class to your toggle `div` and use(assuming you're on different browser): `.your-class-name {
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10 and IE 11 */
  user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */
}`

Answer (score 0):

Use a button not a link then you can style it to get the look you want.

```js
const toggleElements = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle');

toggleElements.forEach((toggle) => {
  const content = toggle.nextElementSibling;

  // Add a click event listener to toggle the content visibility
  toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (content.style.display === 'block') {
      content.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      content.style.display = 'block';
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="toggle">fit</button>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="wrapper-content">
      <p> test1</p>
      <p>test2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, Im still facing the problem

Answer (score 0):

`user-select: none;` prevents the user from selecting and highlighting text

```js
const toggleElements = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle');

toggleElements.forEach((toggle) => {
  const content = toggle.nextElementSibling;

  // Add a click event listener to toggle the content visibility
  toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (content.style.display === 'block') {
      content.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      content.style.display = 'block';
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.toggle a, .content p {
    user-select: none !important;
    -webkit-user-select: none !important;
    -moz-user-select: none !important;
    -ms-user-select: none !important;
    cursor: text !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="toggle">
    <a>Fit</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content" style="display: none;">
    <div class="wrapper-content">
      <p> test1</p>
      <p>test2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```